# Snow and Ice on the Alaskan Highway

Tags: canada, driving, alaska

I need to pull a U-Haul down the Alaskan Highway from Anchorage to Seattle.  I want to know when that road is likely to be clear of winter's snow and ice.

Comment: https://themilepost.com/getting-started/faq-driving-the-alaska-highway/